# change color of button text with makeStyles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Previously, I was styling my button like this:

```
      style={{
        background: '#6c74cc',
        borderRadius: 3,
        border: 0,
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
      }}>
```

This worked well. The text color was white while the background color was the color of the button. However, now I am using this:

```
className={classes.button}>
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    button: {
      background: '#6c74cc',
        borderRadius: 3,
        border: 0,
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
        //fontStyle: 'red',
        
    },
  }),
);
```

While the background color is correct, the text color is not white (when the button is disabled). When the button is not disabled then its fine. Otherwise, it's not. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have set color value as 'red', try changing it to white. It should work.

Comment: Nah, that was just to test. I already changed it to white in the qs before the ans. Thats not the problem

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful to see a codesandbox example, but I suspect that the material button has a color attribute set for disabled elements and thats why the text color is wrong.

Material-ui uses [makestyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook) which uses [jss](https://cssinjs.org/jss-syntax?v=v10.3.0) to create style sheets - so if you create a pseudo selector for its disabled state e.g.

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    button: {
        background: '#6c74cc',
        borderRadius: 3,
        border: 0,
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
        '&:disabled': {
            color: 'white',
        }    
    },
  }),
);
```

You should find that the  correct color is applied.
If not reply with a minimal code sandbox and I'll be happy to take a look :)